# simple ajax post variables not being seen by php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-ui

I've been googling and scratching my head over the below code!  for hours I can't understand any reason for it not to be working.

I'm hoping one of you can shed some light on this...

in the browser dev tools network reports all fine (200)
Console response shows the posted data correctly as:

```
 <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<small></small>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=1)</i>
  11 <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>''</font> <i>(length=0)</i>
</pre>
```

In my php script it only has var_dump $_REQUEST and $_POST both say array 0 empty

my JQuery code is:

```
$(function () {
    $('#test-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Stop form from submitting
        $("select[name='Category']").change(function () {
            const SelectName = $(this);
            const SelectValue = $("select[name='Category'] option").filter(':selected').val();
            const NextSelectRef = $(this).next();
            
            // To make more dynamic we need to be able to get the select name currently it returns the ID value
            console.log(SelectName);
            
            if (SelectName) {
                console.log('Selector name exists');
                
                // Ajax
                if ($.trim($("SelectValue")) != '') {
                    console.log('Prepare to ajax!');
                    
                    //console.log('Data has been serialized' + SelectValue);
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/GetSubCat.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {Category: SelectValue,},
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        error:function(error){
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="test-form" name="form" action="/forms_categories.php"
        method="post">
        <ul>
            <li><label for="">Cocoa Cola 330ml</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="Category" id="id55">
                        <option value="8">Bakery</option>
                        <option value="11" selected="selected">Beverages</option>
                        <option value="9">Meat</option>
                        <option value="10">Poultry</option>
                    </select> <select name="SubCategory" id="SubCategory">
                        <option value="7">Cans</option>
                        <option value="8">Bottles</option>
                        <option value="9">Chicken</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">update</button>
                </div></li>
            <li><label for="">Cocoa Cola 500ml</label>
                <div>
                    <select name="Category" id="id56">
                        <option value="8">Bakery</option>
                        <option value="11" selected="selected">Beverages</option>
                        <option value="9">Meat</option>
                        <option value="10">Poultry</option>
                    </select> <select name="SubCategory" id="SubCategory">
                        <option value="7">Cans</option>
                        <option value="8">Bottles</option>
                        <option value="9">Spirits</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">update</button>
                </div></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your xhr, the data object should be `\`index=${SelectValue}\``. And then you will have `$_POST['index']` containing your select value available in your PHP script.

Comment: Hey Noah, that was a typo on my part.  It's in my original code and I've updated what I posted.  So my question still stands thanks

Comment: First check that //GetSubCat.php resolves correctly.
Then console log the data you are passing to your ajax request before the request happens, please.

Comment: Hey Noah, // was another typo on my part when I removed the directory path, I've updated the post...  console.log(SelectValue) right before ajax call shows correct value.  Anyway if it was empty the if statement above would of caught it and logged an error...

Now you can see why I'm scratching my head...

Comment: How are you linking your jquery snippet to the html ? that's not clear to me. without that linking the post will still work but not the way you may desire. Can you confirm ?

Comment: This is the link: <script type="text/javascript" src="someDir/JQuery/GetSubCat.js"></script>
and it resolves in the dev tools under network

Answer (score -1):

So after much head scratching.  and rewriting of code etc etc. I finally found out that as I'm running on a local WAMP server v3.13 ajax xhr may not work with my server configuration!  It's an out of the box setup, so I'll have to see what I can do to get it working.  Once I do I'll post back as I'm sure many others have unknowingly experienced the same thinking it was their script when it's actually server related and not limited just to WAMP Server flavours...

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.